# Error Running Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I have encountered a time consuming problem in running android studio. every time I open the app on windows 10 enterprise,it comes with a different error!  for example, the fallowing errors have appeared :

```
Error Launching Studio
Error invoking main method
```

an other error on running :

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:95)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.lambda$start$0(PluginManager.java:92)
... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/intellij/openapi/util/io/FileUtilRt, method: getUserContentLoadLimit signature: ()I) Incompatible argument to function
at com.intellij.openapi.application.PathManager.ensureConfigFolderExists(PathManager.java:196)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.checkSystemFolders(StartupUtil.java:195)
at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:118)
at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:34)
... 6 more
```

another error :

```
Internal Error. Please report to 
https://https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

 java.lang.VerifyError: (class: gnu/trove/TObjectHash, method: contains
 signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z) Incompatible argument to function
at com.intellij.util.containers.Interner.<init>(Interner.java:32)
at com.intellij.util.containers.StringInterner.<init>(StringInterner.java:21)
at com.intellij.util.containers.WeakStringInterner.<init>(WeakStringInterner.java:29)
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.<init>(UrlClassLoader.java:168)
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader$Builder.get(UrlClassLoader.java:140)
at com.intellij.ide.BootstrapClassLoaderUtil.initClassLoader(BootstrapClassLoaderUtil.java:69)
at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:32)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

and some other similar errors related to launching Studio referring to intellij and java as mentioned previously

On Version 2.3.2 : Usually While It is connected to the internet, the android studio's panel pops up and freezes , and while offline , the errors appear .

On Version 3.0.1 : in this version there is no pop up panel , the errors appear in this case.

the results alternatively change between mentioned forms!
I even upgraded my windows hoping that the problem would be solved.but it did not!moreover , I have tried several different versions of jdk, Studio and have defined JDK_HOME , JAVA_HOME . the result is annoying.

my system info:

processor : core i3 2120 @ 3.3

installed memory : 4 GB

GPU: Nvidia GeForce 520 GT

Adapter Ram : 2GB

Comment: What is the Android Studio version you are using?

Comment: I Have tried all Similar questions solutions , but They didn't work!

Comment: I use Version 3.0.1

Comment: try older version and see.

Comment: Have you reported the issue?

Comment: I have both tried V2.3.2 and reported the issue.

Comment: Your download could be corrupted.

Comment: I have downloaded several times, moreover, the installation process is completed without any problem.

Comment: If you get different errors each time there might be a problem with your hardware.

Comment: you mean the hardware of the computer which I am working on it with out any problem is out of service?!